# URL encrypt in <a> tag in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, url-rewriting, urlencode

I am developing one secure portal project in `Php codeignitor`. I need to know about encryption of URL in `<a> tag` where the URL is completely visible in the page source. I am very well aware of `urlencode` function in php. I dont want to use it because it can also be decoded as well. so I want solution something looks like below

> Instead Usual way

```
<a href="https://somedomain.com/path1/path2">....</a>
```

> I want something like this

```
<a href="xWAYK4rT3D9VBsheGElFZXtoL5zkfQ">....</a>
```

I have seen this kind of encryption technique where even though it is encrpted, it navigates to current page.

Comment: How do you handle seo? If your pages don't have any seo friendly url?

Comment: Better solution secure your code not url..

Comment: @SRana thank you for your concern but i am not in need of SEO as i mentioned in the first of my question, Its secure portal where it is not commercial product rather it is for purpose of internal service of some business concern.

Comment: write your own encryption method in js. Decrypt it and redirect it using js. use `e.preventdefault()` to stop normal redirection.

Comment: This should just be closed as any encryption or decryption on the client basically null in voids the whole idea of it. The URL will need to be decoded on the client side meaning the user will be able to find out the full string no matter what.

Comment: A link is supposed to be clicked. If it is clicked it needs to be readable by the browser which means that it cannot be encrypted. Whatever you do it will only be some kind of obfuscation, but won't provide any security. It's would be important to understand what you ultimately want to achieve by that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make link itself "xWAYK4rT3D9VBsheGElFZXtoL5zkfQ" , better add unique generating token with your URL : href= "https://somedomain.com/xWAYK4rT3D9VBsheGElFZXtoL5zkfQ"
Use your own token generation code , which can encrypt and decrypt.

$key=pack('H*',"bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");

$codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

$codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt($key, $codeAlphabet,...);

$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt($key, $codeAlphabet,..);

Comment: I think this is on track to be the right answer. The thing to remember (as other have pointed out) is that anything the browser can decrypt the user can decrypt. It would be helpful if the OP explained WHY he wants to hide the URL, especially why it is important to hide the domain. (That makes me suspicious of the OP's intentions.) However, if it's all right to show the domain, then encrypting the rest of the URL on the SERVER and then sending back that token to be decrypted on the server is the way to go.